# Unable to open more than one csv file in the same python program

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My requirement is that I have two CSV files, I need to compare and perform operations on the last column of both the files. I am using pandas to open two CSV files, When I open the second CSV file and try to access any column 
returns the error.

```
import pandas as pd1
import pandas as pd

# comma delimited is the default
df = pd.read_csv("results.csv", header = 0)

spamColumnValues=df['isSpam'].values

df1=pd1.read_csv("compare.csv",header=0)

spamCompareValues=df1['isSpam'].values
```

Getting an error

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1964, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1971, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1645, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3590, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2444, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5280)

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5126)

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1210, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20523)

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1218, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20477)

KeyError: 'isSpam'
```

Can anyone point out my mistake, or it is not possible to do this with pandas?

Both the csv files can be found at

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3XlF206d5UrUENtZlcwd0pVLW8/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3XlF206d5UrbGdJRFM5TURmejQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Add the first column with the column names to both .csv's

Comment: Why do you import 'pandas' two times with different aliases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you don't have a column named "isSpam" in `compare.csv`. You will need to pass `header=None` to `pd.read_csv()` otherwise you'll be capturing the first observation as headers:

```
df1=pd1.read_csv("compare.csv",header=None)
```

and since the columns appear to be the same:

```
df1.columns = df.columns
```

Comment: Seriously? A downvote? Would love to hear the feedback on this.